# Convert UTF-8 file to UTF-16 BE file in Vbscript

Tags: encoding, utf-8, vbscript, data-conversion, utf-16

Is there any method to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 BE in VBscript?

I have this following code, but converts only into UTF-16 LE.
I need the output be in UTF-16 BE.

```
Sub Utf8ToUtf16Le(fileIn,fileOut)

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oStream = CreateObject ("ADODB.Stream")

    With oStream
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .LoadFromFile fileIn
        FSO.OpenTextFile(fileOut, 2, True, True).Write .ReadText
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub Utf8ToUtf16Le(fileIn,fileOut)
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Dim inputStream

    Set inputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With inputStream
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .LoadFromFile fileIn
        .Position = 0
    End With 

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-16be"
        .WriteText inputStream.ReadText
        .Position = 0
        .SaveToFile fileOut, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    inputStream.Close

End Sub
```

If the BOM is needed in the output, we can explicitly add it with

```
    .Charset = "utf-16be"
    .WriteText ChrW(&hFEFF)
    .WriteText inputStream.ReadText
```

or, as pointed by Kul-Tigin, we can change the `.Charset` property from `utf-16be` to `unicodeFEFF`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked very well!
But I have one question: why my `fileOut` does not come with byte order mark? Not that I needed, I just want to understand...

Comment: @skrenato, just guessing, but as by default all vbs strings are UTF-16 probably the encoder does not consider the BOM is needed. If at some point you need it, just add `.WriteText ChrW(&hFEFF)` before the `.WriteText inputStream.ReadText`

Comment: @skrenato replace the charset `utf-16be` with `unicodeFEFF` then it will work as you expect.